# Adding SSRS to Farm...Do I need to install Project Server onto instance?

Tags: reporting-services, project-server

We have a Sharepoint farm with four servers:

Admin
WFE
Search
Workflow

We installed Project onto the farm and are looking to install SSRS into the farm on its own server.  As part of getting the separate server up and running, will we need to install Project after we install Sharepoint in order to join it to the farm?  Or can we just install Sharepoint, join it to the farm, then install SSRS onto it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install Project Server on every server in the SharePoint Farm. Reference:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff686783(v=office.14).aspx#section3

> When you install Project Server 2010 to a farm, Project Server 2010 has to be installed to every application server and Web server in the farm. Therefore Project Server 2010 licenses are required for each server in the farm.